# write NSString to file

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, file

I'm trying to write a string to a file and store that in the applicationSupport folder within my app. But my NSLog() statement doesn't log anything in the debugger. I have tried to go through it with the debugger, and i can see that the content is nil, so i'm guessing that's why it's not outputting anything, but i don't know why it's set to nil. Can anybody see my mistake?

```
 NSString *document = [[[[[[[[description stringByAppendingString:@" "]stringByAppendingString:focus]stringByAppendingString:@" "]stringByAppendingString:level]stringByAppendingString:@" "]stringByAppendingString:equipment]stringByAppendingString:@" "]stringByAppendingString:waterDepth];
//NSLog(@"%@", document);

//get the documents directory:
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *supportDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

//filename
NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:[_nameTextField.text stringByAppendingString:@".txt"], supportDirectory];

[document writeToFile:filename atomically:NO encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];

NSString *content = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filename usedEncoding:nil error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@", content);
```

Comment: That first line should really be a stringWithFormat... https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`filename` is wrong. It should have the following format: `"directory/file.extension"`. You can use the methods [`stringByAppendingPathComponent`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-stringByAppendingPathComponent_) and [`stringByAppendingPathExtension`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-stringByAppendingPathExtension_) to construct such a string.

```
NSString *filename = [supportDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[_nameTextField.text stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"txt"]];
```

---

Also, as a side note, the first line should be rewritten using `stringWithFormat` like this:

```
NSString *document = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ %@ %@", description, focus, level, equipment, waterDepth];
```

Comment: or, even better, `... [_nameTextField.text stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"txt"]];`

Comment: Yes, I was going to change that too. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I tried changing the directory to the applicationSupport, because i store other txt files inside that folder. But now i get a message, that content is a invalid CFStringRef. Any ideas?

Comment: @NielsSønderbæk - You probably should post this in a new question and provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong initialize filename. It should be:

```
  NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", supportDirectory,[_nameTextField.text stringByAppendingString:@".txt"]];
```

it will works! Good luck:)

Answer (score -4):

The

```
NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:[_nameTextField.text stringByAppendingString:@".txt"], supportDirectory];
```

is wrong. It should be:

```
NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:"%@%@",[_nameTextField.text stringByAppendingString:@".txt"], supportDirectory];
```